# How to remove the dictionary key and retain the values only in list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

I have a list of dictionary in my variable , as shown below :

```
category = [ { "S" : "Restaurants" }, { "S" : "Drinks" }, { "S" : "Outdoor Seating" }]
```

I want to remove keys and it should just give me values , output should look like :

```
[Restaurants,Drinks,Outdoor Seating]
```

Note : that length of list is varying everytime , lets say above category variable has 3 key-value pairs . It may be 2 , 4 or some other number next time, But it should return only values .How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using list comprehension to iterate through the list and get all the values of each dict.

```
category = [ { "S" : "Restaurants" }, { "S" : "Drinks" }, { "S" : "Outdoor Seating" }]
new = [list(dicx.values())[0] for dicx in category]
```

output

```
['Restaurants', 'Drinks', 'Outdoor Seating']
```

Comment: Can you tell me that what is the first index [0] representing here ?

Answer (score 2):

The essence of the answer is to loop through the list, and for each dictionary, extract the value(s) you want and stick it in a new list.

Assuming each dictionary only has a single entry with key `"S"`, as in your example, you could do it in one line:

```
l = [d["S"] for d in category]
```

In the more general case, if we assume nothing about the number of entries in each dictionary, the single-line solution becomes only slightly more unwieldy

```
l = [value for d in category for value in d.values()]
```

Personally, I find the multi-line solution a little easier to follow:

```
l = []
for d in category:
    for value in d.values():
        l.append(value)
```

Comment: Sure it's possible, it's trivially converted from your loop to `[value for d in category for value in d.values()]`

Comment: whoa! I've never used that syntax before!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
category = [ { "S" : "Restaurants" }, { "S" : "Drinks" }, { "S" : "Outdoor Seating" }]
for data,cat in enumerate(category):
    for value,key in cat.items():
        category[data]=key
print(category)
```